# Unable to connect .NET 8 API to SQL database

Tags: sql-server, .net-8.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that should connect to a SQL Server 2022 Express (v16.0.1000), but I get the following error in both Event Viewer and stdOut when it tries the connection. It works in my offline SQL Server and running in Visual Studio.

> Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer EventId:
> 2 SpanId: 50083643a27b0777 TraceId: 97319a0c6b30cdd3defe64d219eabc59
> ParentId: 0000000000000000 RequestId:
> 80000217-0002-fd00-b63f-84710c7967bb RequestPath: /api/Login/ApiLogin
>
> Connection ID "18230571301796315670", Request ID
> "80000217-0002-fd00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was
> thrown by the application.
>
> Exception:  System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection
> fatal error.    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior
> runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.DrainData(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowUnsupportedCollationEncountered(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.GetCodePage(SqlCollation collation,
> TdsParserStateObject stateObj)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryProcessEnvChange(Int32 tokenLength,
> TdsParserStateObject stateObj, SqlEnvChange& sqlEnvChange)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
> enlistOK)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
> serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
> Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
> withFailover)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
> serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
> Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
> SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
> timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
> Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
> identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
> newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
> userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean
> applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
> options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
> DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
> DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
> pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
> DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
> allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
> connection)    at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
> outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
> TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at Project.BLL.Services.UserStore.FindByNameAsync(String normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\...\Project.BLL\Services\UserStore.cs:line 303    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByNameAsync(String
> userName)    at
> Project.API.Controllers.LoginController.ApiLogin(LoginModel model) in
> C:...\Project.API\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line 56    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext
> actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor
> executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync() --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)    at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)    at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()

The error happens when the application tried to log in to the database. In the SQL profiler, all I get is this -

> name: login
> TextData: options_text    -- network protocol: LPC  set
> quoted_identifier on  set arithabort off  set numeric_roundabort off
> set ansi_warnings on  set ansi_padding on  set ansi_nulls on  set
> concat_null_yields_null on  set cursor_close_on_commit off  set
> implicit_transactions off  set language us_english  set dateformat mdy
> set datefirst 7  set transaction isolation level read committed
>
> and
>
> name: logout TextData: null

I was thinking it was related to collation issues (currently `Latin1_General_CI_AS`), but there is nothing unusual about the project and it works on the development SQL Server (same version).

The connection string is 100% correct.

I have ran the app through Visual Studio to the live database server and get the same error, but no further details. This tells me it's something on the live SQL Server, but I can't figure it out!

Comment: Are you on the latest version of the SqlClient library? Also 16.0.1000 is the very first release build of SQL2022, you should upgrade to the latest build ASAP https://www.sqlserverversions.com/2021/07/sql-server-2022-versions.html

Comment: I have upgraded to the latest version - v16.0.4105. I still get the error message. I am using the latest SqlClient library System.Data.SqlClient (5.1.4) in the BLL.

Comment: Hmmm not sure. Someone here https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1116 suggests adding `<InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>` to you project file. Which version of Windows are you running on the client and server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out in .net 8, Invariant Globalization is set to true by default in the project properties.

```
<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
```

This needs to be false. After a rebuild and republish it started working!

https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/2239